# How can you change screen in pyautogui

Tags: python, linux, windows, screen, pyautogui

I currently have the problem with pyautogui that it only works on the primary screen. Can I change this somehow?

PS: I have already read the docs, but I found nothing :c

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

```
    cursor = ctypes.wintypes.POINT()
    ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(cursor))
```

You can get the correct position on multiple monitors.

Comment: is there a way to look for pictures using this method?